# Fortran 95 segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have been working on Fortran95 on a Linux operating system. I have made a compiled a code which was done without any error. When I tried to use the compiled file, the result error is reported as,

segmentation fault (core dumped)

As a recovery measure, I have changed the memory allocation to 65535, even then the code reported the same error. What can be done to run the file smoothly?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry but without any source code it's very hard to diagnose what your issue might be. Please edit your question to include a [mcve] (there are also chances that doing so you will find the answer by yourself).

Comment: As @AdrianoRepetti pointed out without seeing the code or error we cann't help. Have you tried compiling with warnings and debugging symbols (for `gfortran` use `-g -O0 -pedantic -Wall -Werror`)?

Comment: Try putting *[fortran] segmentation fault* into the SO search box, and do some research.  You'll almost certainly find the answer to your question.

Comment: This is an abysmally incomplete question.

Comment: I **love** meta. After all these discussions about "be gentle" this question is still open after many hours, just 4 downvotes even if OP didn't even reply to a comment or improved his question. Hey guys, this is like Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

The most frequent reason behind a 'segmentation fault' is an illegal array subscript (like when you want to get A(11) when A is a 1D array of size 10). You may want to add the compiler option

```
-fcheck=bounds
```

to have a more detailed description of your error.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for your answer.  However, in general we try to avoid answering questions such as this one which provide us no opportunity for anything but guesses.  You can see from the comments below the question that people are asking for clarification before answering.  In particular, there's no indication that arrays are involved and we can't be sure that the user's compiler even supports the option `-fcheck=bounds`.